# Recovering data using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

This is the first time that I'm using Fluent NHibernate and I have some doubt's about a constructor class and mapping

**NHibernate_Helper.cs**

```
    private static ISessionFactory objSessionFactory;

    private static ISession objSession;

    public ISession GetSession()
    {
        if (objSessionFactory == null)
        {
            lock (typeof(NHibernate_Helper))
            {
                if (objSessionFactory == null)
                {
                    var config = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();

                    var props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    props.Add("dialect", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dialect"]);
                    props.Add("connection.driver_class", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connection.driver_class"]);
                    props.Add("connection.connection_string", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection.connection_string"].ToString());

                    config.AddProperties(props);

                    string classMapping = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Assembly.Name"];

                    config.AddAssembly(classMapping);
                    objSessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
                }
            }
        }

        if (objSession == null || !objSession.IsOpen)
        { 
            objSession = objSessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        return objSession;
    }

    public IList<T> GetToLinq<T>()
    {
        ISession session = this.GetSession();

        var query = from t in session.Query<T>()
                    select t;

        return query.ToList<T>();
    }
```

**Web.config (Presentation Layer)**

```
<add key="dialect" value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect" />
<add key="connection.driver_class" value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
<add key="Assembly.Name" value="Dashboard.Domain" />
```

**Mapping**

```
public class ReceitaMap : ClassMap<Domain.Receita.Receita>
{
    public ReceitaMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Receita_Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();

        Map(x => x.DataHoraCriacaoRegistro)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.CodigoEmpresa.Empresa_Id)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.CodigoOrigem.Origem_Id)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.CodigoServico.Servico_Id);

        Map(x => x.CodigoEquipamento.Equipamento_Id);

        Map(x => x.CodigoClientePessoa.Pessoa_Id);

        Map(x => x.CodigoVendedorPessoa.Pessoa_Id);

        Map(x => x.DataEmissao)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Quantidade)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Valor)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Table("ind_receita"); // Name of my table in SQL
    }
}
```

I inserted a single row in my `Ind_Receita` table, just for testing purposes, but the code below always returns 0 rows. I think exists something wrong with my mapping.

```
        var context = new NHibernate_Helper();
        var receitas = context.GetToLinq<Receita>();
        return receitas;
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: your **fluent** mapping is/seems to be correct.
Secondly: this kind of weird behaviour would happen, if the **xml** mapping is not Embedded resource.

And there would be the answer. The `ISession` above is built by Configuration/Factory, which expects the **xml** mapping to be placed in some library as `Embedded resource`. Not sure about the element shown above:

```
<add key="Assembly.Name" value="Dashboard.Domain" />
```

Because as documented here: [1.1. Getting started with NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#quickstart-intro), the `<session-factory>` should have:

```
<mapping assembly="Dashboard.Domain" />
```

That would be the way without fluent... But with fluent, we should use the:

- [Fluent configuration](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-configuration)

The syntax - to recieve a Session Factory - should be like this *(see the doc [link](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-configuration) for more details)*:

```
Fluently.Configure()
  .Database(/* your database settings */)
  .Mappings(/* your mappings */)
  .ExposeConfiguration(/* alter Configuration */) // optional
  .BuildSessionFactory();
```

So, I would suggest, change your Configuration code. Use Fluent configuration, and correctly pass to `Mappings()` the library which contains the `ClassMap` implementations *(instead of xml)*

Comment: I'll make these corrections. This was a legacy code which we didn't use the Fluent NHibernate. I know that is a boring question, but this is my first time with Fluent.

Comment: Look NHibernate is amazing, and if possible, it is priceless to get it runing ;) the above links in my answer shold help

Comment: With your explanation, it's working now, I put the Fluenty configuration instead the NHibernate configuration and I made some corrections at my Mapping, putting the `.Column("column_name_in_database")`

Comment: Awesome! Great, NHibernate is the way to go ;) Enjoy it